# Counting Firebase items with certain property

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm using these to connect to my FireDB

```
afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase
participantsList: AngularFireList<any>;
participants: Observable<any[]>;
```

Then I do this to get the data

```
this.participantsList = afDatabase.list('/paticipants');

this.participants = this.participantsList.valueChanges();
```

How I can count the items in there, and how I can count items with a certain property?

Comment: where you want to get the count, in `component` or `template`?

Comment: I want to count it in the code, in the typescript file, cause I need to count other thing with other properties too.

Comment: Cause I have difficulty to understand how to deal that participants variable. I can't filter it in any way, I tried with normal filter but without positive results, I want to filter them by name, surname and by paid property too.

Comment: ok i saw your previous question. so why don't you use a `pipe` filter?

Comment: Sure I can use one of them, but how, I'm new in Ionic and I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Transform the source observable to get the length of the emitted array.

```
this.participantCount: Observable<number> = this.participants.map(ps => ps.length)
```

If you want to filter by having a certain property, filter that list.

```
this.adminCount = this.participants.map(ps => ps.filter(p => p.admin).length)
```